# Android Null Checker

Tags: android, database, checkbox, null, equals

I have a program that relates to a database. I start out my program by inserting a row using the following command.

```
    long id = db.insertMajor(null, null, null, null);
```

it works perfect. I than alter the information but lets ignore that since for the time being I commented out all those lines. Now I want to check and see if it is null which is should be. If it is not null than I would like to check a checkbox. if it is null than I want to leave the box unchecked. So far I have this line to test.

```
    String change = db.getMajorTitle(value).getString(1);
    if (change.equals(null)) {
    filled = false;
    }
```

the filled boolean will check the box or not. If the database field is filled or not I always get a checkmark. Whats wrong?

UPDATE:
Since no one has figure it out I will post most of my code to try and help figure it out. I have also reset my emulator to ensure there is not problems with corrupted data.

```
    chk1.setChecked(checker(1));
    chk2.setChecked(checker(2));
    chk3.setChecked(checker(3));
    chk4.setChecked(checker(4));
    }

    boolean checker(int value){
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        boolean filled = false;
        db.open();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            String change = db.getMajorTitle(value).getString(1);
            if (change == null) {
                filled = false;
            }else{
                filled = true;
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return filled;
    }
```

If someone copies this and it works can you please tell me what might be wrong with my emulator or eclipse or whatever. Thanks everyone for there input.

FINISHED:
I noticed that at another part in my program I changed null to "". I would like to thank everyone for being right and showing me different ways to code it.

Comment: What class is db? Are you showing us your own API? How would anyone know what happens inside it?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? `change.equals(null)` should throw an exception when change is null because you can't call members of null objects. Try `change == null` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need if statements for this.

```
filled = (change != null);
```

Comment: Tried this and it still checks them all.

Comment: That means that either (1) your code for setting the checkboxes doesn't run correctly (easy to test, just hard code `filled` to be `false` and see what happens), or (2) the database isn't returning `null` (also easy to test, output `change` to the log and see what it is).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that the code for the checkboxes runs correctly so I'm going to attempt option 2. How do you output to the log?

Comment: Use the functions of the `Log` class. There are lots of examples online about how to use it, for example [this](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) if you're using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (change.equals(null)) {
> ```

If  `change` instance is not `null`, the above condition **always** returns `false`. Read [Object equality constraints](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for more info.
If you want to check against `null` use

```
if( change == null) {
  // change is null, update filled field
} else {
  // change is not null, update filled field
}
```

> If the database field is filled or not
>   I always get a checkmark. Whats wrong?

I guess that you would have initialized the `filled` field as `true` and never set it as `false` since your `if` condition always returns `false` or throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Tried this as well. It still checks them all

Answer (score 0):

User ExceptionHandling mechanism. then you will succeed. Like

```
try {
  if(change!=null)
  {
    //do ur work,if not null
  }
  else
  {
    // do some thing
  }
}catch(NullPointerException e)
{
  //do  ur work,if null.
}
```

Comment: This didn't check any of them